Change DHTML element size live/on-screen using Javascript Loop
I want to create a button that shrinks in size until it's too small to see (and then expands outward from the center point.) The button is a circle and my issue is .JavaScript, the first function successfully calls the function that changes the size of the element.
//script menu js

function changeMenu(){
  const parent1 = document.querySelector('.menuSelection');
  activeMenu = parent1.classList.contains('visible');
  hiddenMenu = parent1.classList.contains('hidden');
  buttonClicked();
  if(hiddenMenu){
    parent1.classList.remove('hidden');
    parent1.classList.add('visible');
  }
  else{
    parent1.classList.remove('visible');
    parent1.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
function buttonClicked(){
  const button1= document.getElementById('dropdownButton');
  console.log('Button Clicked Start');
  for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    button1.style.width -= "10px";
    button1.style.height -= '10px';
    console.log('Loop');
  }
  console.log('Button Function End.');
}
console.log('Outside')

const button = document.getElementById('dropdownButton');
button.addEventListener('click',changeMenu)

I am having an issue with trying to get a circle button to change size when I click on it. I want the button to shrink by 10px each loop which I have a for loop. Okay the problem is that the BUTTON doesn't CHANGE SIZE. (caps to help people who need a tdlr) THE FUNCTION DOES spit OUT DEBUG statements so the function fully runs. NO ACTUAL CHANGE ON THE FRONT END(I believe I'm using that term right.)
What have I done?
Written Debug statements for when the function starts, ends, and when the loop inside the function runs. All of the statements are outputted to the console. I was expect the button to shrink inward on itself since the function scales down 1:1 which keeps the circle shape.
Here is a link to my github ringofdeath.github.io pages link and you can check the code from there and from the pictures provided.CSS for Button that needs to change in size.
#dropdownButton{
    
    height: auto;
    
    border: solid;
    border-color:rgb(50, 107, 107);
    background-color: rgb(50, 107, 107);
    border-radius:50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display:inline-block;

    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

(EDIT) I forgot to include that maybe the issue is because I can only assume with my knowledge that you can't do major on live element changes without react, but maybe I read the react homepage wrong. REACT IS NOT a part of this program it is only DHTML.

We can't debug images. Please add a [mcve] to your question and see [ask]

Your loop just takes 50px off the button dimensions without showing anything in between (JS is a simple, single threaded, environment, the JS will complete before the screen is repainted). A simpler method might be to look into either transition or animation in CSS.

You had several issues.

The usage of the word DHTML in 2024 is obsolete
You didn't introduce delay in your loop
You tried to width -= "10px" so that didn't work.

I think this kind of things is better done with CSS3 which has transition property and transform: scale both should make some effect.


//script menu js
const button = document.getElementById('dropdownButton');

function buttonClicked() {
  console.log('Button Clicked Start');
  button.classList.add("shrink");
  

  setTimeout(function() {
    button.classList.remove("shrink");

  }, 1500)

}
button.addEventListener('click', buttonClicked)
.button {
  height: auto;
  border: solid;
  border-color: rgb(50, 107, 107);
  background-color: rgb(50, 107, 107);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: 1500ms;
}

.button.shrink {
  transform: scale(0)
}
<div id="dropdownButton" class="button"></div>



